# Extract HTML from page child blocks

Tags: notion-api

I'm relatively new to the notion API - as far as I can tell there's no straightforward way to do what I want, but thought I'd ask in case I've missed something.

As the question title suggests, I want to be able to query a notion page and get its full contents as HTML, rather than having to parse each block. Is there any way to do this?

I thought, given notion exports to html, there'd be a method inbuilt to the api, but it appears not. The [only solution I've found](https://github.com/asnunes/notion-page-to-html) requires the database to be public, which doesn't really suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

We've created a service to [get any Notion page content as an HTML via the API](https://www.nocode-scripts.com/notion-api-html). You can convert private or public Notion pages to HTML via official API.

Please write to me if this is what you were looking for. I'll be glad to get feedback.

Comment: Would you open source this and share it as a library. Need this for converting private Notion pages to a raw HTML